# Tradingview - Plot big amount of data

Tags: pine-script

I really like tradingview though the programming language pine drives me crazy. 
Maybe somebody can tell me what to do or point me in the right direction.

Since there are no arrays and no possibility to retrieve data from an external source, I try to generate the pine code for an indicator centrally on my server.

So I have a value for every **daily** bar and this actually for many symbols. All I want is to plot a simple line based on this data.

Programming the indicator does not cause me any problems, but I am looking for a practicable way to implement it.

Thats how I would go. Are there better solutions for such tasks?

```
study("My Script")



tick = 
      year == 2019 and month == 1 and dayofmonth == 1 ? 123 : 
      year == 2019 and month == 1 and dayofmonth == 2 ? 871 :
      year == 2019 and month == 1 and dayofmonth == 3 ? 872 : 870


plot(tick)
```

Thanks

Eric

Comment: How do you generate those numbers: 123, 871, 870 etc? Should it be exacly a number or you can use some info about a simbol? Maybe you could put a label with info symbol, resolution, year, month, dayofmonth ect?

Comment: It needs to be the numbers. Since they are the result of a calculation based on historical data.

Answer (score 0):

) Pretty ingenious. Can't think of a better way. Maybe some others here will. You may run into limit of embedded ternaries (don't know what it is; maybe Michel T. here knows) and compiled tokens, which is 50K but there's no way to know current usage.

With large code bases it is sometimes useful to break it up in different functions. Could also help control size of ternaries.

Comment: I can't say about the limit. Most likely follows the same restriction for amount of operations and size of a script

Comment: The restriction should not be a problem, since I only need to plot the data for max. one year. Maybe I need to create one script per symbol. Thanks for your help